# как актуализировать данные в mongodb с помощью их id и делать insert?

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

помогите решить задачу, нужно обновлять данные в MongoDB, точнее документы в одной коллекции, иногда могут из сайта через api приходить 10 событий, иногда 8, как сделать чтобы была автоматическая актуализация. Код не работает. Ошибка выходит 
**com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl** cannot be cast to **com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor**

```
public static void getObject() throws Exception {
     String api = "api_сайта";
     String dbURI = 
"mongodb://api:мой_пароль@10.10.30.14:27017/smartdata";
     MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(dbURI));
     MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("smartdata");

    URL url = new URL(api);
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en");
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());
     String str = new String();
     while (scan.hasNext()) 
        str += scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    //getting json array
    JSONObject obje1 = new JSONObject(str);
    JSONArray jArray = obje1.getJSONArray("places");
    for (int i = 0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object3 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        int id = object3.getInt("id");
        String slug = object3.getString("slug");
        String name = object3.getString("name");
        String summary = object3.getString("summary");
        String phone = object3.getString("phone");
        String address = object3.getString("address");
        String description = object3.getString("description");
        String date = object3.getString("date");

        String url1 = object3.getString("url");
        String url_ticketon = object3.getString("url_ticketon");
        MongoCollection<Document> sobt = db.getCollection("sobt");
        Document filter = new Document("id",id);
        Document content = new Document();
        content.append("slug", slug);
        content.append("name", name);
        //content.append("images", images);
        content.append("summary", summary);
        content.append("phone", phone);
        content.append("address", address);
        content.append("description", description);
        content.append("date", date);
        content.append("url", url1);
        content.append("url_ticketon", url_ticketon);
        Document update = new Document("$set", content);
        sobt.updateMany(filter, update);
        MongoCollection<Document> ttt = db.getCollection("sobt");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("id", "2040");
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor =  ttt.find(query);
        if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
            // Document doesnt exist so create one

            List<Document> writes = new ArrayList<>();
            Document d2 = new Document("id", 2040);
            d2.append("name", "Volyua");
            writes.add(d2);
            ttt.insertMany(writes);

            System.out.println("found!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not found");
                    }

}
```